# how to select values from a table using between condtion

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want a single condition for getting values between dates.

i have a table name user and a column date,i want to fetch the values from database using date condtion.

```
select sum(visitor) AS V FROM user  WHERE date  < '21-05-2012' AND dDateTime > '11-05-2012' 
select sum(visitor) AS c FROM user  WHERE date  < '21-06-2012' AND dDateTime > '11-06-2012'
select sum(visitor) AS s FROM user  WHERE date  < '21-07-2012' AND dDateTime > '11-07-2012'
select sum(visitor) AS g FROM user  WHERE date  < '21-08-2012' AND dDateTime > '11-08-2012'
```

i want these four query in a single sql statement

Comment: you want 1 result or 4 results ?

Comment: i am using these four query i want to make this four query in a single statement

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
select 
    sum(CASE WHEN date  < '21-05-2012' AND dDateTime > '11-05-2012' THEN visitor ELSE 0 END) AS V, 
    sum(CASE WHEN date  < '21-06-2012' AND dDateTime > '11-06-2012' THEN visitor ELSE 0 END) AS c,
    sum(CASE WHEN date  < '21-07-2012' AND dDateTime > '11-07-2012' THEN visitor ELSE 0 END) AS s,
    sum(CASE WHEN date  < '21-08-2012' AND dDateTime > '11-08-2012' THEN visitor ELSE 0 END) AS g
FROM 
    user
```